# Avoid Counting a Delimiter with Cut

Tags: bash, cut

I have a file that looks like this;

```
"id","string"
"10","john smith"
"20","smith, john"
```

On this I run `cut -d , -f 2`, which returns

```
"john smith"
"smith"
```

In the second row, I want to return `"smith, john"`. Is there a solution to this using `cut` that ensures the specified delimiter is not treated as one when contained within a pair of double quotation marks?

Comment: No. `cut` is only suitable for files with unquoted/unescaped delimiters. You want a language with a proper CSV parser.

Comment: it cannot possibly close the quote on "smith on second line.

Comment: Thank you both - the answer from Cyrus below works, but not for the most general case. I'll look into `awk` a bit more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'",' 'NR>1 {print $2}' file
"john smith"
"smith, john"
```

In short: NR>1 skips first line and changing Field Separator by -F'",' one can print second  field/column.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
cut -d , -f 2- file
```

Output:

```
"string"
"john smith"
"smith, john"
```